# Haskell http-client set User Agent String

Tags: haskell, web-crawler

I'm writing a web crawler in Haskell with Scalpel.
Basic code are:

```
Main :: IO ()
Main = do
  request <- parseRequest weblink
  p <- httpLBS request >>= return . getResponseBody

  result <- do
    r <- return $ scrapeStringLike (L8.unpack p) torrentS
    return . fromJust $ r

  -- append
  mapM_ putStrLn $ result
```

The target website doesn't return the results. I suppose it checks the user agent string and respond differently to a real browser and a crawler.

So how should I customize the User Agent String in `http-client`?
or `wreq?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User agent is a [HTTP header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#page-46), so you just use an API for setting headers. E.g. [`requestHeaders`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.6.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:requestHeaders) in `http-client` (note that it is a setter, so you can use it as `request{requestHeaders=blah}`)

Comment: Apart from the customized user agent string, is there anything else I should simulate?